# Is my dropdown menu (on change submit function) crawlable?

Tags: php, jquery, post, googlebot

i have the following function to switch between the FAQ categorys.

```
<form name="choose_faq" action="" method="post">
        <select name="cat" onChange="document.choose_faq.submit()">
          <option value="">- {FAQNAME} -</option>
          <!-- BEGIN faqs -->
          <option value="{faqs.ID}"></option>
          <!-- END faqs -->
        </select>
      </form>
```

The crawler from Visual SEO Studio dont use the dropdown menu to crawl the children pages. But what is with the googlebot, can he crawl the dropdown?

Kindly regards!

Comment: Open your browser and view the source. Do you see the options tags? If so, so does Googlebot.

Comment: Hey John, yes in the sourcecode i see the following example: <option value="3">TEST3</option>
                            <option value="1">TEST1</option>
                            <option value="2">TEST2</option>

Comment: Then Googlebot sees it, too

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer and have a nice weekend! :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Googlebot can see your options when crawling your page.

Google bot starts with reading your robots.txt file and obeys your blocking requests.  It also reads the `<title>` tag in your `<head>` and your `<meta name="description">` tag.  Finally, it reads all of your content.

From: https://blog.kissmetrics.com/the-way-google-scans/

Googlebot can also see your content delivered by javascript.  It has been doing so since 2008 and has been improving its capacity to do so ever since.

From: http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157

Comment: @tobiass all good questions on SO deserve an answer / resolution. Please offer this answer the green tick so that your question is deemed resolved.  If there is something else you would like me to mention in the answer, please leave a comment.